# Многопоточная работа с БД: Можно ли как-то выбирать данные из таблицы без UPDATE признака обработки?

Tags: база-данных, алгоритм, python-3.x, многопоточность, асинхронность

Есть БД на postgresql и приложение на Python 3 (psycopg2). Приложение берет из таблицы n записей и отправляет из в веб-сервис (requests) получая некие результаты, которые нужно в последствии записать в таблицу сделав `UPDATE` по ранее полученным данным. В таблице есть признак обработки записи: `1` - обработано, `0` - нет.

Вопрос: Я хочу прикрутить многопоточность\асинхронность к приложению. Можно ли как-то выбирать данные из таблицы без `UPDATE` признака обработки? То есть, в двух потоках выполняемых паралельно я хочу выбрать разные данные, 2й поток должен выбрать данные, которые небыли выбраны первым потоком. Существуют ли какие-то механизмы того как это можно сделать без `UPDATE` и `NOT IN`? Ведь `UPDATE` придется делать для каждой записи, а `NOT IN` сам по себе не быстрый.

Comment: Простейший способ - использовать то самое поле признака обработки, расширив его смысл. Например, пусть Null означает, что запись не обрабатывалась, 0 - что запись обработана, а любое другое значение - это идентификатор копии приложения, которое в данный момент ведёт обработку этой записи. Соответственно поток сначала пытается захватить запись (или группу записей) на обработку (`UPDATE table SET proc=@my_id WHERE proc IS NULL LIMIT n`), потом обрабатывает их (по `WHERE proc=@my_id`), а по завершении обработки помечает обработанными (`UPDATE table SET proc=0 WHERE proc=@my_id`).

Comment: если вопрос об улучшении производительности, то стоит минимальный, но полный пример кода создать, который демонстрирует проблему. Тяжело (и ошибочно как правило) производительность детально обсуждать, без конкретных измерений. [mcve]

Comment: **Akina** Спасибо. Идея хорошая, попробую реализовать посмотреть как работает.

Comment: **jfs** Сейчас готовлю только прототип. Вопрос был задан с целью получения общей информации хотя бы о том, какой алгоритм заложить в прототип.

Comment: Вообще говоря, вам надо смотреть в сторону чего-то вроде `SELECT FOR UPDATE` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html). Вы же не хотите, чтобы все ваши 100500 потоков обрабатывали одну и ту же запись?